# Update with Substring

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hi is it possible to have a update SQL statement with a SELECT substring SQL statement?

How would I convert this to an update statement?

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING([Col1], 2, LEN([Col1])-2)
FROM table1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE table1 set Col1 = SUBSTRING([Col1], 2, LEN([Col1])-2)

Comment: @briskovich can you add that as an answer. Seems like that's what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 UPDATE table1 set Col1 = SUBSTRING([Col1], 2, LEN([Col1])-2)
```